# Finding common characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Q: What is the best approach to tackling this problem?

For example, if the two values are "chocolate" and "cockroach" then the function should return "choa"

RESEARCH:

I have found find(),or making it into a list witch is helpful structuring the function.

CODE: This is where I am having issues!

```
Value1 = input("Please input a word: ")
Value2 = input("Please input a second word: ")
[How do I find similar letters in two words]
print(similar_letters)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
Please input a word: hello 
Please input a second word: hey
letters in word are : 'he'
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how your example works, exactly?

Comment: @Christian Careaga I fixed it

Comment: @arshajii I added some more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you meant the common characters? use sets, as long as you don't mind that they remove duplicates and change the order of the elements:

```
s1 = set("chocolate")
s2 = set("cockroach")

"".join(s1 & s2)
=> "ahco"
```

Comment: Okay, I have poorly explained myself. I have cleared things up. This is what I was aiming for.

Comment: if you care about the order of the output, you can sort it after the union operation, like `''.join(sorted((s1 & s2),key=lambda x: 'chocolate'.index(x)))`

Comment: Downvoters: _this_ is what OP wanted, care to reconsider your downvotes?

Comment: That may be, but it's not what he **asked** originally.  I didn't downvote your answer, though:  it was correct enough and the question (as it was proved later) not completely clear.

Answer (score 3):

**Incorrect** original answer (left in place for comments' sake).  Result is wrong in many cases, specifically when sample `Value1` and `Value2` are permuted.

```
output= [ x for x in list(Value1) if x in list(Value2) ]
```

**Correct** answer (IMHO) if the desired result is to represent in the output characters that appear both in `Value1` and `Value2` more than one time.

```
''.join( [ x * min(Value1.count(x),Value2.count(x)) for x in sorted( set(Value1) | set(Value2) ) ] )
```

For the sample `Value1='chocolate'` and `Value2= 'cockroach'`, output is `'acchoo'` (any pun here? :-) ).  `sorted` has as only function make the characters appear alphabetically (and, thus, make stable the exact resulting string).

Comment: Why the -1?  It's not exactly what you were looking for, but then you give "choca" as the desired answer, duplicating the "c".

Comment: This works great. This is is simple and explains it nicely, but @Mario Rossi is right, I didn't want duplicating letters.

Comment: @MarioRossi this returns `chocoa`, not `choca`.  Also I dislike the unnecessary `list()` call, strings are already iterable.  (I am not the downvoter, but I understand his vote)

Comment: @roippi I tried to make my original one-liner as self-explanatory as possible. But you are right, just tested my answer and it's not the (erroneous?) example result either. And, BTW, even this example was inconsistent with a reasonable interpretation: it should effectively have been `'chocoa'` as in `'chocolate'` and `'cockroach'` are 2 common `'o'`s (as there are 2 common `'c'`s).  My original answer is **incorrect** for a different reason.

Comment: Corrected the answer.  Now it **effectively** produces my original understanding of the question.  It could be useful to somebody else.